# Very simple Latitude/Longitude to WGS84 conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, latitude-longitude, wgs84

As from [here](https://portal.opentopography.org/apidocs/#/Public/getGlobalDem), I'm using the OpenTopography API to download a *geoTiff* heightmap, and it uses **4 WGS84 Coordinates**, but the map I've supplied to the user gives back longitude/latitude coordinates. I'm very new to GIS, so I was wondering if there was some kind of equation for converting them.

Comment: Commonly, a bounding box is specified as the SW corner and the NE corner- that is, 2 coordinates. However, as @Spacedman explains, this site uses the 4 "lines" that define the box- the southern and northern extents (latitude) and the western and eastern extents (Longitude). You can extract 4 unique coordinates where these intersect, but you only need 2 to define the box- S and W, and N and E. They are all latitude-longitude and require no equation to convert.

Comment: @LeighBettenay Thanks! I've recently just figured this out, and I'm sure it would be a massive help to anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"WGS84" coordinates are (usually) latitude and longitude.

There are lots of different definitions of latitude and longitude, based on different earth shapes or different reference points for 0 longitude. What's called "WGS84" is usually a specific standard for lat-long, more formally called "EPSG Coordinate Reference System Code 4326".

These are the coordinates used by GPS location systems, and should be the default lat-long system for any new data. Sometimes you find older data based on a different earth-shape model or a non-standard 0 longitude meridian. But what I see on that web page API is (99.999%) probably all "WGS 84 lat-long".

[image]